# how to recognize the object I detect in video frames is a people or a car

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a problem to detect object in images or video frames.

I have a task that is detect some people or something who enter into the sight of web camera, and then my system will be alarm.

Next step is recognize which kind of thing the object is, in this phase I know use [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to detect line, circle, even rectangle. But when a people come into the sight of camera, people's profile is more complex than line, circle and rectangle. How can i recognize the object is people not a car.

I need help to know that.
thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify if you want to detect whole human bodies or just faces. There are special methods for face detection (and body detection too).

Comment: it is not to detect who is the person,what i want to do is to detect what kind of thing it is ,a car ,a person,or a dog ?

Comment: Okay, it is much more complicated. But, it is relatively simple if you have a constant background (a camera is not supposed to move). You can just subtract background and find the difference. When _segmentation_ is done, recognition might be done easily. So, let me know if background is fixed, and I'll then post my ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you look at the paper "[Histograms of Oriented Gradients for Human Detection](http://www.acemedia.org/aceMedia/files/document/wp7/2005/cvpr05-inria.pdf)" by Dalal and Triggs. They used [Histograms of Oriented Gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram%5Fof%5Foriented%5Fgradients) to detect humans in images

Comment: oh very good thank you information, I will try my best to read the thesis.

Comment: hi Amro can you give me some more information about recognize people and car or animal. I have a assignment to do this.

Comment: Amro, could you recommend any implementations? Is original author's code OK? http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/soft/olt/

Answer (score 0):

I think one method is to use Bayesian analysis on your image and see how that matches with a database of known images. I believe some people run a wavelet transform to emphasize more noticeable features.

Comment: -1: This answer is way too general. Bayesian analysis of what, how do you do the match?